# Problems using asynctask to call a function in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I tried to work with Asyntask but it didn't worked...
I need to put this function in asyntask:

```
public  String [] orderAddresses (ArrayList<String> itemArrey, EditText fromPosition, EditText toPosition)
```

If someone can help me with that I will be very happy :)

**Edited

```
    class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String []> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
    super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
        ArrayList<String> iA=(ArrayList<String>)params[0];
        EditText fPosition= (EditText)params[1];
        EditText tPosition= (EditText)params[2];
         return orderAddresses(iA, fPosition, tPosition) ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String [] result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}

Task1 myTask = new Task1();    
String []bestRoute= myTask.execute(itemArrey, fromPosition, toPosition);
```

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask to String[]"
-What should I do?

Comment: u can't, a function inside a function is not possible. You can only call it after declaring it outside somewhere. By the way why you need to add function inside there??

Comment: what is this method for?

Comment: I have 'NetworkOnMainThreadException' and the solution for that is to use asynctask...@Saqib

Comment: Can you post more of your code? and the error that you get? You should call the above function in the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask, and then get the result back to your UI thread in onPostExecute().

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t988JQHDbX0 is a good example of how to use AsyncTask if you are new to it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with 2 edits after you have updated your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

### First a little bit on how AsyncTask actually works.

When you call `yourAsyncTask.execute(args)` on your UI thread the following happens:

`onPreExecute()` is called to setup stuff on the ***UI thread***. This allows you to access UI elements.

then `doInBackground()` is called with the arguments to `.execute()` and is run on a ***background thread***. The type of this argument is indicated by the first generic parameter in your subclass (in your case `Void`). Data used in `doInBackground()` have to be accessible by the thread, and in general you should provide the needed data here when you call `.execute()` to begin with.

During execution it is possible to call `publishProgress()` within `doInBackground()`, which will delegate updates to the UI thread through `onProgressUpdate()` (where you can access UI elements). The type of data given here is indicated by the second generic parameter of your `AsyncTask` (In your case `Void` again).

When `doInBackground()` is done it gives the result to `onPostExecute()` which is run on the `UI thread`. The type of the result is indicated by your third generic parameter (`String[]` in your case). But calling super.onPostExecute() does not really do anything for you - you need to use the data return from `doInBackground()` and do something with it - update your UI or something. Nothing happens automatically. Since `onPostExecute()` is run on the UI thread you can access your UI elements here (which you cannot in `doInBackground()`).

### So for your code:

First of all you call `doInBackground()` with `Void`. It cannot access UI data outside the UI thread, so when you add Edit texts arguments to this call it cannot access them. You should give the contents through `.execute()`. And set your first generic parameter to a type that can contain all the data you need for `doInBackground()`. You could e.g. have `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` that holds two arraylists, one which is itemarray, and the other which holds the String contents of the two EditTexts (just an idea).

Your method signature will then look like this: `doInBackground(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>... args)` - which gives you access to the data that you want within `doInBackground()`.

Second - once you reach `onPostExecute()`. you never do anything with the result. So if you use the String[] to e.g. update a `ListView`, then you should call `setAdapter()` here, or whatever you want to do with your result.

I hope this helps and makes sense.

**EDIT**: Based in your updated question you call `.execute()` with three parameters which will of course fail, as you have told AsyncTask that you will not provide any parameters (You give it `Void` on the first parameter in `<Void, Void, String[]>`).

**EDIT 2**: You start your worker thread like this:

```
String []bestRoute= myTask.execute(itemArrey, fromPosition, toPosition);
```

This will not work as `myTask.execute()` returns an instance of itself (in other words an `AsyncTask`), and not a `String[]`. This is why you get a type mismatch in that line. You need to handle the result in `onPostExecute()`!